# What are some alternatives to Paypal, that would let users create a very simple payment landing page?

Tags: paypal

I'm looking for an alternative to Paypal that would let users create very simple payment page (if possible, on a subdomain) in a few clicks.

Ideally, it would be developer-friendly or appeal to the dev. community (I would use it to receive small payments for code-related tasks)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com). It's simple, unified, and I will trust it more than a small business's stand-up payment website because the security is done through Google.

Comment: To me, Checkout seems more geared towards business owners and merchants than individuals, doesn't it? And can I create a simple landing page with Checkout? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are really meaning by "landing page" but yes, you can just add the Google Checkout link somewhere on your page when your users are "ordering", and then Google can fill in the rest. I guess you'll have to go to the link I put in my answer and check it out before anyone will know if it will work for your situation. But, I know individuals use it very well too. Basically it's for anyone who may not be able to make a high-class payment themselves.. be it individual, small business, merchant, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

- [2checkout.com](http://2checkout.com)
- [regnow](http://regnow.com)
- [paypal](https://www.paypal.com/) - You don't need a paypal account to buy from you.
- [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com)

Comment: What about the landing page creation? (e.g. Flavors.me or about.me, but with payment)

Answer (score -1):

Stripe also works. There are a ton out there though. I am not a fan of Google Checkout myself though, its all about your preferences

Comment: This doesn't provide answer.